# Imshow specific part of a video

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a video capture, nothing fancy:

```
VideoCapture cap("video.mp4"); 
Mat frame;

while (true)  { 
cap >> frame;
//some other stuff...
}
```

Then I imshow the video which is 800, 600 in resolution.
My question is, how do I imshow predefined areas of the video, for instance in the coordinates 50x, 100y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just show the crop for each frame, which can be obtained defining a Region of Interest (ROI) with a `Rect`:

```
VideoCapture cap("video.mp4"); 
Mat frame;
Mat crop;
Rect roi(50, 100, 200, 200); // Your Region of Interest

while (true)  { 
    cap >> frame;
    crop = frame(roi);
    imshow("Cropped Video", crop);
    waitKey(1);
}
```